# selenium incognito cannot click on element or link c#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I open ChromeDriver using selenium in incognito but i cannot click on element or link although if i open chrome browser manually in  incognito/private mode it work normally , here is my code:

```
void OpenChrome(
          string Website,
          int TimeToWaitInMinutes,
          string FolderPathToStoreSession,
          int Index,
          out int ChromeProcessID)
        {

            try
            {

                //رقم ال process
                int ProcessID = -1;

                //زمن للانتظار حتي يفتح الموقع
                var TimeToWait = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TimeToWaitInMinutes);

                //خيارات فنح المتصفح
                ChromeDriverService cService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

                //اخفاء شاشة ال dos السوداء
                cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                //خيارات اخري
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");//تكبير نافذة المتصفح

                //
                options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
                options.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability("useAutomationExtension", false);
                //
                options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
options.AddArgument("--incognito");
                //مسار فولدر ال session
                options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + FolderPathToStoreSession);
                
                
                //تعريف اوبجكت كروم
                drivers_Ref[Index] = new ChromeDriver(cService, options, TimeToWait);

                //رقم ال process
                ProcessID = cService.ProcessId;

                //فتخ الموقع
                drivers_Ref[Index].Navigate().GoToUrl(Website);

                //الانتظار حتي يتم تحميل الصفحة
                WaitForPageLoad(drivers_Ref[Index]);

                ChromeProcessID = ProcessID;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //اذا حدث Error
                //نغلق الكروم
                if (drivers_Ref[Index] != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        drivers_Ref[Index].Close();
                        drivers_Ref[Index].Quit();
                    }
                    catch { }
                    drivers_Ref[Index].Dispose();
                    drivers_Ref[Index] = null;
                }

                ChromeProcessID = -1;

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

i use webdriver 3.141, chromedriver 92
and there is no error happens but the click dot not work either on button or link, what is the problem and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try this is debug mode and see if an error is occurring?

Comment: i use try catch an no error happens, but also i will do it

Comment: Have you tried to remove the flags other than the `--incognito` and see what happens?